# How to round field in SAP Crystal Report 2011?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Rounding of static value is different from rounding DB field value in SAP B1 crystal report 2011

I have **609,437.50** from Database when I go to Field Format and then round field I get **609,437**

I have **609,437.50** in formula as static value when I round I get **609,438** which is correct same as excel

[image: With decimal number picture]

[image: Without decimal number]

How can I round Database field and get value like **609,438** while I have **609,437.50**?

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Are in field format rounding and decimal set at same value?

Comment: Yes, are same value

Comment: Then you likely have database value actually different from xxx.50. What data type is your value in database - some float or decimal or money? If float, then you have to convert it to decimal first - float values are inexact and rounding may behave strangely. If decimal or money, then you may have more decimal places filled (like xxx.499), which rounds down again.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's solved

Comment: So post this as solution, please, so others can make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have database value different from xxx.50.

What data type is your value in database - some float or decimal or money?

If float, then you have to convert it to decimal first - float values are inexact and rounding may behave strangely.

If decimal or money, then you may have more decimal places filled (like xxx.499), which rounds down again. You need either accept your results or round to two decimals first; this can be visually better, but is wrong mathematically.